# Copy a message from one queue to another queue

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have created two queues in ActiveMQ: one is `Master` and another is `Audit`.

All of my messages first come into `Master`. I want all of the messages in `Master` to be automatically copied (not moved) to the `Audit` queue.

Is there any configuration in ActiveMQ or Camel to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the [Wire Tap pattern](https://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html). For example:

```
<route>
    <from uri="jms:master_queue"/>
    <wireTap uri="jms:audit_queue"/>
    <to uri="to_do_something"/>
</route>
```

Answer (score 3):

Apache ActiveMQ has that baked in out of the box. You can use its support for mirror queues

- https://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html

The following comes from the linked page:

### Enabling Mirrored Queues

By default Mirrored Queues is disabled; as enabling it will cause a virtual topic to be created for each queue you use.
To enable Mirrored Queues, set the useMirroredQueues property on BrokerService or add the following inside the  element in the Xml Configuration:

```
<destinationInterceptors>
    <mirroredQueue copyMessage = "true" postfix=".qmirror" prefix=""/>
</destinationInterceptors>
```

This would make a topic named "*.qmirror" for each queue on your Broker.